# jQuery UI: Sorting TRs in a tbody sometimes fails because of too little space

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a small table with two table rows.

I want to make them sortable with jQuery UI sortable.

If you try to put the second row before the first row, sometimes it does not work.

It seems that the sorter needs more space.

How can I resolve this problem?

```
<div>
 <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="handle">X</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="handle">X</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uYGer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the [tolerance-option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-tolerance) to `pointer` improves the Situation.

Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uYGer/1/